# Модальное окно с картинкой

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как вызвать child компонент, по которому кликнули, в модальное окно?
Например, нажимаю по картинке, в модальном окне появляется она же с блоком для комментария.

Answer (score 0):

Делаете для своего child компонента отдельную функцию:

```
renderChild = () => {
    return <img src="your.path" />
}
```

Вызываете эту функцию внутри parent компонента:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
             // ваш код
             {this.renderChild()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

И для модального окна, эту функцию передаете в props-ах:

```
<Modal 
    image={this.renderChild}
/>
```

Внутри render-а в модальном окне делаете

```
render() {
    return (
         <div>
              {this.props.image()}
         </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Окей,спасибо
А если у меня массив из фотографий который я мапом создаю?
Я пытался пройтись по всему масиву и найти нужный элемент через event.target = images[i], но Реакт отвергает всякие мои попытки